# Pandas: Set variable to value in cell, if another cell on same row contains string

Tags: python, pandas

Let's say my Pandas `DataFrame` contains the following:

```
Row    Firstname    Middlename Lastname
…
10     Roy         G.          Biv
11     Cnyder      M.          Uk
12     Pan         T.          One
…
```

If a cell in `["Lastname"]` contains `"Biv"`, I would like to set the Python variable `first_name =` to `"Roy"`.

I've been away from Pandas for a while and am unsure on the right way to accomplish this. I've looked at ways to combine `df.iloc`/`df.loc` etc with `df.at/df.where` and `str.contains` but have to admit I'm kind of lost on the proper way to put the conditional together with setting the variable.

In (poor, **incorrect**) pseudo-code, I'm looking for:

`first_name = df["Firstname"][np.where([df["Lastname"].str.contains("Biv") ...`

Comment: Sorry are you after `df.loc[df['Lastname'].str.contains('Biv'), 'Firstname'] = 'Roy'`

Comment: @EdChum I'm not looking to set a cell value in the `df`, but to set a "normal" Python variable (`foo = bar`) by retrieval from the Pandas cell, if there is a string match in `["Lastname"]`. Thanks :)

Comment: So just `firstname = df.loc[df['Lastname'].str.contains('Biv'), 'Firstname'][0]`

Comment: What's the desired behaviour if there isn't exactly one "Biv"?

Comment: @JonClements I decided to leave that out of the scope of this question, but perhaps it's inseparable. In *my* case I would just like to get the first match.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want just the scalar value then you can access the first value in the result array and assign this:

```
firstname = df.loc[df['Lastname'].str.contains('Biv'), 'Firstname'][0]
```

Note that really you should check if it's not empty though:

```
if len(df.loc[df['Lastname'].str.contains('Biv'), 'Firstname']) > 0:
    firstname = df.loc[df['Lastname'].str.contains('Biv'), 'Firstname'][0]
```